# Swift Gaussian Blur an image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, ios8, gaussian

I've been developing an app for quite a while now and am soon to finish. I have been blurring some images using the `UIImage+ImageEffects.h` library, but now I want to switch to **Gaussian blurring** an `UIImage`

Is there any library or something similar that would allow me to gaussian blur an image in my app?

Answer (score 20):

I use following in my app.

```
 func applyBlurEffect(image: UIImage){
    var imageToBlur = CIImage(image: image)
    var blurfilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
    blurfilter.setValue(imageToBlur, forKey: "inputImage")
    var resultImage = blurfilter.valueForKey("outputImage") as CIImage
    var blurredImage = UIImage(CIImage: resultImage)
    self.blurImageView.image = blurredImage

  }
```

Comment: You can also use [__GPUImage__](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) to do many image filters too. _GPUImage_ is sometimes claimed to be faster than _Core Image_. But if you don't do extensive blurring (like animated blurring), I think _Core Image_ is the way to go :D

Comment: This is the way to go; it's a true Gaussian blur convolution. Keep in mind, though, that it's a little slow on iOS!

Comment: @SikhapolSaijit Good point, thanks for reminding us of GPUImage.

Comment: Warning - this takes a few seconds to run. Definitely not practical if you need the blur on demand.

Comment: Don't use literal strings for the keys. CoreImage provides proper constants such as `kCIAttributeTypeImage` and `kCIInputRadiusKey`. And `CIFilter` has `outputImage` property.

Answer (score 5):

I think [UIBlurEffect](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/index.html) is what you want, if you want to avoid the delay. The second half of [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial) tutorial on Gaussian blur techniques in iOS 8 walks you through adding a `UIBlurEffect` to a `UIImage`.